# Does StackOverflow have any servers which don't return content length?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, hyperlinks, server

I'm trying to debug something reported in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383209/how-do-i-get-the-size-of-a-download-when-a-head-request-doesnt-report-contentle). The OP is using `https://stackoverflow.com/` as a test to check file size (content-length). OP claims that StackOverflow.com returns 0 or -1, but I and another user have reported no issue. I did note that the code in the question divides the result which returns 0, still waiting to hear back from OP if that's the case or not.

Could this be that this OP is hitting a different server which doesn't return the content length?

Comment: AFAIK, a logged in user always hits the same server on SE. You *might* have better luck trying to replicate this as a anonymous user.

Comment: Well this is using something which wouldn't be logged in

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't heard back yet from the OP of the original question, regarding whether or not the issue was related to the division. But I've come to the conclusion that OP realized that was the case and didn't want to admit to it.

The issue is that the OP was dividing the content length by `1048576`. Since the returned content length of `http://stackoverflow.com/` is `194569`, it came out to be `0`. I'm not sure however where the OP got a `-1`. I'm also not sure if that `-1` was from StackOverflow or another tested server.

Comment: And that is why you always cast to `float`.

Comment: @michaelb958 s/`float`/`double`

Comment: @michaelb958 Are you suggesting we cast length integers to floating points? Well, [if PHP's doing it](http://use.perl.org/use.perl.org/_Aristotle/journal/33448.html), it _must_ be the best thing to do!

Comment: @ColeJohnson I was suggesting that the OP of the OQ use a float in his division. (I do know you're being sarcastic about PHP.)

Comment: @AdamMaras Oops. Been too long since I was anywhere near a static-typed language.

Comment: @michaelb958 I knew you were serious, but it took me a minute because at first I thought you meant cast the returned `Content-Length` to `float`. As for using a `float`y? I'd say the number is too heavy and might drown unless you use `double`

Comment: In case you didn't get that. I was referencing how a float (pool floaty) might be too big (large) to be held by it, and instead should use double ("double" as in twice).